# Using docker for unit test

Tags: mysql, unit-testing, docker

I run a MySQL container with `--net=host` option.

So now i can make unit test using:g:

> self.db = MySQLdb.connect(host="127.0.0.1", user="XYZ", passwd="XYZ",
>   db="TEST_DB")

The problem is when I try to dockerize my unit test, linking the container with my MySQL container, the `127.0.0.1` IP is not valid. I need to use the real ip for the MySql container, or use the DNS (`/etc/hosts` file).

So I need to alter the ip `127.0.0.1` for the name of the MySQL host.

I imagine that there is a better way to do this? I can, for example, alter the `/etc/hosts` file of my development enviroment.

Answer (score 1):

Docker links update the `/etc/hosts` file in the linked containers.

Use the name of the container you have linked to (find it in the `/etc/hosts` file) to reference the database in your tests.

```
self.db = MySQLdb.connect(host="db-container-name", user="XYZ", passwd="XYZ", db="TEST_DB")
```

[docker-compose](https://docs.docker.com/compose/) will also do this for you (it's just a wrapper for Docker and uses links underneath), or you can use the `--add-host` flag to manually add an entry to a container's `/etc/hosts` file as per [this](https://docs.docker.com/reference/run/#network-settings):

```
$ docker run -it --add-host db-static:86.75.30.9 ubuntu cat /etc/hosts
172.17.0.22     09d03f76bf2c
fe00::0         ip6-localnet
ff00::0         ip6-mcastprefix
ff02::1         ip6-allnodes
ff02::2         ip6-allrouters
127.0.0.1       localhost
::1             localhost ip6-localhost ip6-loopback
86.75.30.9      db-static
```

Comment: Thanks! But how can I use it on my development envrimoment. I need to connect to this container on my enviroment. What host do i use?
I run docker run --name=XYZ --net=host xpto/xpto, and the try to connect using XYZ. If i put XYZ on my hosts file, it works. Is it the best practice?

Comment: Ok! I will try to put --add-host. I read it again, and it alter the hosts file of the container.